# Fatal error when trying to display picture from database

Tags: swift, xcode, fatal-error

So I am trying to display the image that a user has selected and uploaded to Firebase Database. I have this snippet of code that displays their username, a label, and their profile image. Here is is a screenshot of where I am getting the error. I have looked at other forms about this error but have tried to apply it and still getting the same issue. Thank you for the suggestions of how to fix this in advance!

[[image: Code Snipper With Error[1]]
[image: setProfilePic Func]

Comment: Use `Data` and `URL` instead of `NSData` and `NSURL` in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems most likely that `data` is nil and so `UIImage()` is not being created.  You can test it and throw an error, if appropriate:

```
enum DataError: Error {
    case noData
}

guard let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)!) else {
    print("Could not create valid NSData from databaseProfilePic")
    throw DataError.noData
}
```

If you don't like `guard` then you may consider assigning in an `if`.

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)!) {
    self.setProfilePic(imageView:self.imageView1, imageToSet:UIImage(data: data as Data)!)
}
```

I'd be looking at checking the URL `databaseProfilePic` and the results of getting that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unwrap value of `databaseprofilePic` using `if let` like

```
if let profilePic = dict!["photoURL"] as? String {

  //your code to set profile pic

}
```